# 2 Vertical background colors for a font icon

Tags: css, less, font-awesome

I'm trying to create a flickr icon using font-awesome, and would like to represent the colors accurately (which means a purple and blue dot on each side of the icon).  I'm trying to do this with LESS using gradients.  But I've been unable to figure out how to vertically align the gradients (I can only figure out horizontal).

What I have so far:

```
.fa-flickr:before {
    color: #fff; 
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #0062da 100%, #0062da 100%),
                      linear-gradient(to right, #ff0084 100%, #ff0084 100%);
    background-size: 100% 50%, 100% 50%;
    background-position: 0 0, 0 100%;
    transform: rotate(90%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;            
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FQJhE/2/

This leaves the gradients stacked in the wrong direction, and shows extra color outside the icons.  I'd appreciate any pointers on how to get the gradients rotated, and any help on the excess colors would be great as well.

Comment: looks like we need some screenshot/image to show exactly what you want.

Comment: I want it to look like the flickr logo: http://nomadbrush.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/flickr-logo1.png But I'd like to use font-awesome and CSS rather than an image file. I'm open to alternative ways of doing this, but I was trying to use background gradients to shade each dot.

Comment: You cannot use a gradient on text (which an icon-font is) like that...although there is a -webkit 'hack' - http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/gradient-text/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is what you want:

```
.fa-flickr {        
    color: #fff; 
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #0062da 50%, #ff0084 50%);   
    background-size: 80% 80%; 
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;        
}
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/FQJhE/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Reference [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FQJhE/5/)

Instead of using two different gradients, why not use a single gradient with stops that start and end at the same point.

```
.fa-flickr:before {
    color: #fff; 
    background-size: 100% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0% 50%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        to right,
        #0062da 50%,
        #ff0084 50%
    );
}
```

As for the overflow I've simply made it smaller and given it a vertical offset to fit inside the icon.

Comment: Also helpful, though I'm going to accept King King's more concise answer.